# Disable horizontal scroll on body and enable on a specific div

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my website for a responsive layout, and i stuck now on that problem..
i have disabled horizontal scrolling on the body with:

EDIT:
Thanks for help, i have fixed it changing width: 1182px to width: 100%; on .letterBar

```
body {
   width: 100%;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

However i need to enable the horizontal scroll on a specific div on the website, the body width is around 480px (smartphone), i tried to use overflow-x: scroll; on my style but don't work:

```
.letterBar {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #212121;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:0;
    font-weight: lighter;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    width: 1182px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    padding: 0px 2px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.letterBar a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 9.4px 16.82px;
    margin: 2px 0px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #d0d0d0;
    background: #191919;
}
```

My div stucture is:

```
<div class="letterBar">
                <a href="/letra/all/">ALL</a>
                <a href="/letra/a/">A</a>
                <a href="/letra/b/">B</a>
                <a href="/letra/c/">C</a>
                <a href="/letra/d/">D</a>
                <a href="/letra/e/">E</a>
                <a href="/letra/f/">F</a>
                <a href="/letra/g/">G</a>
                <a href="/letra/h/">H</a>
                <a href="/letra/i/">I</a>
                <a href="/letra/j/">J</a>
                <a href="/letra/k/">K</a>
                <a href="/letra/l/">L</a>
                <a href="/letra/m/">M</a>
                <a href="/letra/n/">N</a>
                <a href="/letra/o/">O</a>
                <a href="/letra/p/">P</a>
                <a href="/letra/q/">Q</a>
                <a href="/letra/r/">R</a>
                <a href="/letra/s/">S</a>
                <a href="/letra/t/">T</a>
                <a href="/letra/u/">U</a>
                <a href="/letra/v/">V</a>
                <a href="/letra/w/">W</a>
                <a href="/letra/x/">X</a>
                <a href="/letra/y/">Y</a>
                <a href="/letra/z/">Z</a>
            </div>
```

but this doesn't work and doesn't enable the horizontal scroll on the div...

Anyone knows how to do that? thank you!

Comment: As long as your `div` isn't limited in width, an `overflow` will never occur. Please add an MCVE. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Keep in mind that for horizontal scroll to work, the child of your div with `overflow-x: scroll;` needs to be wider than the parent. You currently don't have enough information to give an answer.

Comment: @sallf i have edited the topic with all detailed informations..

Comment: You are explicitly setting `width: 1182px;` so your content never causes an overflow in that element.

Comment: By the looks of it you are confusing what is overflowing what.